# Java - Split array at first instance of value

Tags: java, arrays

The method below receives `byte[] b` of indeterminate length.  It contains a string of characters to be printed to a console-style window.  I would like to split `b` at the first line-feed character, so that that character is included in the first array.  However, at the moment this throws an `ArrayOutOfBoundsError`, because `stringBytes` and `extraBytes` are declared with zero size.  How can I get around this problem?

```
byte[] stringBytes = {};
byte[] extraBytes = {};
int i = 0;

while(i < b.length) {
    stringBytes[i] = b[i];
    if(b[i] == '\n' && i + 1 != b.length) {
        while(i < b.length) {
            extraBytes[i - stringBytes.length] = b[i++];
        }

        break;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: You could convert the whole `byte[]` to a String and split the string on `\n`.

Comment: You'll have to initialize `extraBytes` _after_ you know how long it will be.

Comment: Either initialize your arrays like this: `byte[] stringBytes = new byte[b.length]` and shrink the arrays later on or use `List`s and transform those to arrays afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather build a `String` out of the bytes and use the String APIs.

However, if you really need to do the byte operations that you can declare `stringBytes` and `extraBytes` as `List<Byte>` such as you can add as many values as needed without knowing their size.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
byte[] stringBytes;
byte[] extraBytes;
int i = 0;

while(i < b.length) {
    if(b[i] == '\n' && i + 1 != b.length) {
        break;
    }

    i++;
}
stringBytes = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(b, i+1);
extraBytes = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(b, i+1, b.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) as a light-weight expandable array of bytes:

- To add a byte use the `write` method.
- To get the bytes that you have written so far, use the `toByteArray` method.

For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stringBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream extraBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int i = 0;

while(i < b.length) {
    stringBytes.write(b[i]);
    if(b[i] == '\n' && i + 1 != b.length) {
        i++;
        extraBytes.write(b, i, stringBytes.length - i);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```